# Create 2 line plots in the same figure with common y range Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, line-plot

I would like to make a 2 line plots in the same plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [0.53884, 0.53878, 0.53898, 0.53662, 0.53748, 0.5398, 0.53894, 0.53732, 0.53744, 0.54052, 0.54402, 0.54178] 
x2 = [54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9]

x = range(len(x1))

top_lim = max( max(x1), max(x2) ) + 0.001
bottom_lim = min( min(x1), min(x2) ) - 0.001
plt.ylim(bottom_lim, top_lim)

plt.plot(x, x1)
plt.plot(x, x2 ,color='r')

plt.show()
```

However, this gives me a blank figure.
How can I get the correct plot?

Comment: Hi, is there a particular reason for computing yourself the limits of the plots?  I have just checked what happens removing the `plt.ylim(bottom_lim, top_lim)` statement and Matplotlib is perfectly able to nicely draw your two lines…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem in your code is the `ylim` you can try the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [0.53884, 0.53878, 0.53898, 0.53662, 0.53748, 0.5398, 0.53894, 0.53732, 0.53744, 0.54052, 0.54402, 0.54178]
x2 = [54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9]

x = list(range(len(x1)))

top_lim = max( max(x1), max(x2) ) + 5
bottom_lim = min( min(x1), min(x2) ) - 5
plt.ylim(bottom_lim, top_lim)

plt.plot(x, x1)
plt.plot(x, x2 ,color='r')

plt.show()
```

Due to the fact the values between `x1`,`x2` then both line where at the edges of the plot thus you could not see it.

Comment: @AsmitaPoddar what is the right plot? it seems fine from the given values in the example.